# When is the pImageIndex of vkAcquireNextImageKHR returned?

Tags: asynchronous, vulkan

I'm following this [tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Drawing/Frames_in_flight) for Vulkan. My understanding is that vkAcquireNextImageKHR returns before it completes and thats why we need to wait at vkQueueSubmit for it to finish but if thats the case then how can we know that the imageIndex we pass to recordCommandBuffer points to the the next image if vkAcquireNextImageKHR hasn't finished executing yet?

```
void drawFrame() {
        vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
        vkResetFences(device, 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

        uint32_t imageIndex;
        vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

        vkResetCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[currentFrame], /*VkCommandBufferResetFlagBits*/ 0);
        recordCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[currentFrame], imageIndex);

        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
        submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

        VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = {imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame]};
        VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = {VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT};
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

        submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffers[currentFrame];

        VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = {renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame]};
        submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
        }

        VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo{};
        presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

        presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = {swapChain};
        presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

        presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

        vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue, &presentInfo);

        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more correct to say that `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` performs a swapchain image acquire operation. This operation makes the image available to your application for rendering purposes. And it is this operation which may not be finished when the function returns.

Figuring out which image is to be acquired is not the same thing as actually doing the acquire operation. If the function returns successfully, then the index it gives you is the index of the image that will be acquired.